# RegularExpression Attribute - Passing in a property field of a class

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, validation, attributes

I have created a class MobileNumberAnnotation that has a property which specifies the regex expression. Now that when I specify the RegularExpressionAttribute how do I tell it to get the value of this property as the pattern?

```
public class MobileNumberAnnotation
{
    public string MobileFormat = "^(07(\\d ?){9})";
}
```

I tried doing the following but I don't know why it doesn't work as it is expecting a a string pattern.

```
    [Required]
    [RegularExpressionAttribute(MobileNumberAnnotation.MobileFormat)]
    public int MobileNumber { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like:

```
[RegularExpression("^(07(\\d ?){9})", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Phone Number")]
```

Comment: *Assuming you are correctly writing your regular expression.

Comment: I know you can do that. But thanks for the help anyways

Answer (score 1):

If you change your declaration of `MobileFormat` to be a const, this should fix the problem

```
public const string MobileFormat = "^(07(\\d ?){9})";
```